# NodeJS app failing to build on heroku... PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, heroku, phantomjs

My app doesn't use phantomjs as a direct dependency, nor does it use karma - so I'm really confused as to why my app will no longer compile on Heroku.  Is it possible to force all packages to use a more recent version than 1.9.7-1?

```
5301 verbose linkStuff   '/tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect/node_modules' ]
5302 info linkStuff methods@0.0.1
5303 verbose linkBins methods@0.0.1
5304 verbose linkMans methods@0.0.1
5305 verbose rebuildBundles methods@0.0.1
5306 info install methods@0.0.1
5307 info postinstall methods@0.0.1
5308 info build /tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
5309 info preinstall karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2
5310 verbose linkStuff [ false,
5310 verbose linkStuff   false,
5310 verbose linkStuff   false,
5310 verbose linkStuff   '/tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/node_modules' ]
5311 info linkStuff karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2
5312 verbose linkBins karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2
5313 verbose linkMans karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2
5314 verbose rebuildBundles karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2
5315 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin', 'phantomjs' ]
5316 info install karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2
5317 info postinstall karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2
5318 info build /tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
5319 info preinstall phantomjs@1.9.7-1
5320 verbose linkStuff [ false,
5320 verbose linkStuff   false,
5320 verbose linkStuff   false,
5320 verbose linkStuff   '/tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules' ]
5321 info linkStuff phantomjs@1.9.7-1
5322 verbose linkBins phantomjs@1.9.7-1
5323 verbose link bins [ { phantomjs: './bin/phantomjs' },
5323 verbose link bins   '/tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin',
5323 verbose link bins   false ]
5324 verbose linkMans phantomjs@1.9.7-1
5325 verbose rebuildBundles phantomjs@1.9.7-1
5326 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
5326 verbose rebuildBundles   'adm-zip',
5326 verbose rebuildBundles   'kew',
5326 verbose rebuildBundles   'mkdirp',
5326 verbose rebuildBundles   'ncp',
5326 verbose rebuildBundles   'npmconf',
5326 verbose rebuildBundles   'rimraf',
5326 verbose rebuildBundles   'which' ]
5327 info install phantomjs@1.9.7-1
5328 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
5329 info phantomjs@1.9.7-1 Failed to exec install script
5330 error phantomjs@1.9.7-1 install: `node install.js`
5330 error Exit status 1
5331 error Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.7-1 install script.
5331 error This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
5331 error not with npm itself.
5331 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
5331 error     node install.js
5331 error You can get their info via:
5331 error     npm owner ls phantomjs
5331 error There is likely additional logging output above.
5332 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
5333 error command "/tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
5334 error cwd /tmp/build_6198f9bd-484a-4d57-8f77-b337ced7ab58
5335 error node -v v0.10.29
5336 error npm -v 1.4.14
5337 error code ELIFECYCLE
5338 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Here's my npm list...

```
myapp@0.0.1
├─┬ apn@1.5.2
│ └── q@1.0.1
├─┬ aws-sdk@2.0.0-rc.19
│ ├── aws-sdk-apis@2.0.13
│ ├─┬ xml2js@0.2.4
│ │ └── sax@0.6.0
│ └── xmlbuilder@0.4.2
├─┬ bugsnag@1.4.0
│ └── stack-trace@0.0.9
├── chai@1.6.1
├── connect-flash@0.1.1
├── connect-redis@1.4.7
├─┬ connect-session-sequelize@1.0.0
│ └── debug@0.7.4
├── cron@1.0.4
├─┬ debug@1.0.2
│ └── ms@0.6.2
├─┬ email-templates@1.0.0
│ ├── async@0.9.0
│ ├── ejs@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ glob@4.0.2
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ └── once@1.3.0
│ ├─┬ handlebars@1.3.0
│ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.3.6
│ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │     └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ jade@1.3.1
│ │ ├── character-parser@1.2.0
│ │ ├── commander@2.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ constantinople@2.0.0
│ │ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.13
│ │ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │ │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ │ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ │ ├─┬ monocle@1.1.51
│ │ │ └─┬ readdirp@0.2.5
│ │ │   └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
│ │ │     ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ │     └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8
│ │ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.1
│ │ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5
│ │ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │ │     └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ │ └─┬ with@3.0.0
│ │   └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.13
│ │     ├── async@0.2.10
│ │     ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │     ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │     │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ │     └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│ ├─┬ juice2@0.6.0
│ │ ├── batch@0.5.0
│ │ ├── commander@2.2.0
│ │ ├── cssom@0.3.0
│ │ ├─┬ jsdom@0.10.6
│ │ │ ├─┬ contextify@0.1.8
│ │ │ │ ├── bindings@1.2.0
│ │ │ │ └── nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── cssstyle@0.2.14
│ │ │ ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.7.2
│ │ │ │ ├── domelementtype@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ ├── domhandler@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ ├── domutils@1.5.0
│ │ │ │ ├── entities@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13-1
│ │ │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│ │ │ ├── nwmatcher@1.3.3
│ │ │ ├─┬ request@2.36.0
│ │ │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.3
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│ │ │ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│ │ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
│ │ │ └── xmlhttprequest@1.6.0
│ │ ├── slick@1.12.1
│ │ └─┬ superagent@0.17.0
│ │   ├── cookiejar@1.3.0
│ │   ├── debug@0.7.4
│ │   ├── emitter-component@1.0.0
│ │   ├── extend@1.2.1
│ │   ├── formidable@1.0.14
│ │   ├── methods@0.0.1
│ │   ├── mime@1.2.5
│ │   ├── qs@0.6.5
│ │   └── reduce-component@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ less@1.7.1
│ │ ├─┬ clean-css@2.1.8
│ │ │ └── commander@2.1.0
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.34.0
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.3
│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│ │ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ │ └─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │   └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ node-sass@0.8.6
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
│ │ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
│ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ │ ├─┬ mocha@1.18.2
│ │ │ ├── commander@2.0.0
│ │ │ ├── diff@1.0.7
│ │ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.3
│ │ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│ │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── growl@1.7.0
│ │ │ └─┬ jade@0.26.3
│ │ │   ├── commander@0.6.1
│ │ │   └── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ │ ├── nan@0.8.0
│ │ ├── node-watch@0.3.4
│ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│ │ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
│ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ └─┬ sinon@1.10.2
│ │   ├─┬ formatio@1.0.2
│ │   │ └── samsam@1.1.1
│ │   └─┬ util@0.10.3
│ │     └── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├─┬ styl@0.2.7
│ │ ├─┬ commander@1.1.1
│ │ │ └── keypress@0.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ css-whitespace@1.1.0
│ │ │ └── debug@0.7.4
│ │ ├─┬ rework@0.18.3
│ │ │ ├── color-parser@0.1.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ commander@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ └── keypress@0.1.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ css@1.4.4
│ │ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.6.0
│ │ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.3.2
│ │ │ ├── hsb2rgb@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── mime@1.2.9
│ │ │ ├── rework-inherit@0.2.1
│ │ │ └── rework-visit@1.0.0
│ │ ├── rework-mixins@1.1.1
│ │ └── stdin@0.0.1
│ ├─┬ stylus@0.45.1
│ │ ├── css-parse@1.7.0
│ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
│ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ │ └── sax@0.5.8
│ ├─┬ swig@1.3.2
│ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│ │ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
│ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.13
│ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│ └── underscore@1.6.0
├─┬ express@3.4.8
│ ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
│ ├─┬ commander@1.3.2
│ │ └── keypress@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ connect@2.12.0
│ │ ├── batch@0.5.0
│ │ ├── bytes@0.2.1
│ │ ├─┬ multiparty@2.2.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13-1
│ │ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ │ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│ │ │ └── stream-counter@0.2.0
│ │ ├── negotiator@0.3.0
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ ├── raw-body@1.1.2
│ │ └── uid2@0.0.3
│ ├── cookie@0.1.0
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
│ ├── debug@0.8.1
│ ├── fresh@0.2.0
│ ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.1
│ ├── methods@0.1.0
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
│ └─┬ send@0.1.4
│   └── mime@1.2.11
├─┬ express.io@1.1.13
│ ├── async@0.1.22
│ ├── coffee-script@1.4.0
│ └── underscore@1.4.3
├─┬ grunt@0.4.5
│ ├── async@0.1.22
│ ├── coffee-script@1.3.3
│ ├── colors@0.6.2
│ ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
│ ├── eventemitter2@0.4.13
│ ├── exit@0.1.2
│ ├─┬ findup-sync@0.1.3
│ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
│ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ └── lodash@2.4.1
│ ├── getobject@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ glob@3.1.21
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.3
│ │ └── inherits@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1
│ │ ├── lodash@2.4.1
│ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
│ ├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
│ ├── hooker@0.2.3
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
│ ├─┬ js-yaml@2.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.15
│ │ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
│ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
│ │ └── esprima@1.0.4
│ ├── lodash@0.9.2
│ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ nopt@1.0.10
│ │ └── abbrev@1.0.5
│ ├── rimraf@2.2.8
│ ├── underscore.string@2.2.1
│ └── which@1.0.5
├─┬ grunt-env@0.4.1
│ └── ini@1.1.0
├─┬ grunt-mocha-test@0.7.0
│ └─┬ mocha@1.13.0
│   ├── commander@0.6.1
│   ├── diff@1.0.7
│   ├─┬ glob@3.2.3
│   │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│   │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│   │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│   │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│   ├── growl@1.7.0
│   ├─┬ jade@0.26.3
│   │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0
│   └── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── grunt-nodemon@0.2.1
├─┬ jade@1.0.2
│ ├── character-parser@1.2.0
│ ├── commander@2.0.0
│ ├─┬ constantinople@1.0.2
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.13
│ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├─┬ monocle@1.1.50
│ │ └─┬ readdirp@0.2.5
│ │   └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
│ │     ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │     └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8
│ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4
│ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0
│ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.1
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │     └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ └─┬ with@2.0.0
│   └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.0
│     ├── async@0.2.10
│     ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│     ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│     │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
│     └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
├── lodash@2.4.1
├─┬ mocha@1.10.0
│ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ ├── diff@1.0.2
│ ├─┬ glob@3.2.1
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.3
│ │ ├── inherits@1.0.0
│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├── growl@1.7.0
│ ├─┬ jade@0.26.3
│ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
│ └── ms@0.3.0
├── moment@2.6.0
├── moment-timezone@0.0.6
├─┬ newrelic@1.7.1
│ ├── bunyan@0.14.6
│ ├─┬ continuation-local-storage@3.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ async-listener@0.4.5
│ │ │ └── shimmer@1.0.0
│ │ └─┬ emitter-listener@1.0.1
│ │   └── shimmer@1.0.0
│ └── yakaa@1.0.0
├─┬ nodemailer@0.6.5
│ ├── directmail@0.1.8
│ ├── he@0.3.6
│ ├─┬ mailcomposer@0.2.11
│ │ ├── dkim-signer@0.1.2
│ │ ├── follow-redirects@0.0.3
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├─┬ mimelib@0.2.16
│ │ │ ├── addressparser@0.2.1
│ │ │ └─┬ encoding@0.1.7
│ │ │   └── iconv-lite@0.2.11
│ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│ ├── public-address@0.1.1
│ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13-1
│ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│ └─┬ simplesmtp@0.3.32
│   ├── rai@0.1.11
│   └── xoauth2@0.1.8
├─┬ nodemon@1.0.20
│ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ ps-tree@0.0.3
│ │ └─┬ event-stream@0.5.3
│ │   └─┬ optimist@0.2.8
│ │     └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ └─┬ update-notifier@0.1.10
│   ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
│   │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
│   │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
│   │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
│   ├─┬ configstore@0.3.1
│   │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
│   │ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.0.2
│   │ │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.15
│   │ │ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
│   │ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
│   │ │ └── esprima@1.0.4
│   │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│   │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│   │ ├── object-assign@0.3.1
│   │ ├── osenv@0.1.0
│   │ └── uuid@1.4.1
│   ├─┬ request@2.36.0
│   │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│   │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│   │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.3
│   │ │ ├── async@0.9.0
│   │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│   │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│   │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│   │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│   │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│   │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│   │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│   │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│   │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│   │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│   │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│   │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│   │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│   │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│   │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│   │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│   │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│   │ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│   │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
│   └── semver@2.3.0
├─┬ passport@0.1.18
│ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3
├─┬ passport-local@0.1.6
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3
├─┬ passport-stub@0.1.5
│ └── coffee-script@1.6.3
├─┬ pg@3.3.0
│ ├── buffer-writer@1.0.0
│ ├── generic-pool@2.0.3
│ ├── nan@0.6.0
│ ├── packet-reader@0.2.0
│ ├── pg-types@1.3.0
│ └─┬ pgpass@0.0.3
│   └─┬ split@0.3.0
│     └── through@2.3.4
├── redis@0.10.3
├─┬ safari-push-notifications@0.0.1
│ ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
│ └── bindings@1.1.1
├─┬ sequelize@1.7.8
│ ├── bluebird@1.0.8
│ ├─┬ circular-json@0.1.6
│ │ └── wru@0.2.7
│ ├── commander@2.1.0
│ ├── dottie@0.1.0
│ ├── generic-pool@2.0.4
│ ├── lingo@0.0.5
│ ├── moment@2.5.1
│ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ ├─┬ sql@0.35.0
│ │ ├── lodash@1.3.1
│ │ └── sliced@0.0.5
│ ├── toposort-class@0.3.1
│ ├── underscore.string@2.3.3
│ └── validator@3.2.1
├── simple_blitline_node@2.2.0
├─┬ sinon@1.7.3
│ └─┬ buster-format@0.5.6
│   └── buster-core@0.6.4
├─┬ socket.io@0.9.17
│ ├── base64id@0.1.0
│ ├── policyfile@0.0.4
│ ├── redis@0.7.3
│ └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.16
│   ├─┬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1
│   │ └── zeparser@0.0.5
│   ├── uglify-js@1.2.5
│   ├─┬ ws@0.4.31
│   │ ├── commander@0.6.1
│   │ ├── nan@0.3.2
│   │ ├── options@0.0.5
│   │ └── tinycolor@0.0.1
│   └── xmlhttprequest@1.4.2
├─┬ supertest@0.8.0
│ ├── methods@0.0.1
│ └─┬ superagent@0.15.1
│   ├── cookiejar@1.3.0
│   ├── debug@0.7.4
│   ├── emitter-component@1.0.0
│   ├── formidable@1.0.9
│   ├── mime@1.2.5
│   └── qs@0.6.5
├── underscore@1.5.2
├── validator@1.1.3
└── view-helpers@0.1.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck with the same issue with the same ghost "karma-phantomjs-launcher" dependency that even prevents from deploy when removed from package. 
After researching for a couple of days with no much luck I realized that is a Heroku cache refresh problem. ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#build-cache)

1) Install heroku repo plugin

> heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git

2) Clear the repo module cache

> heroku repo:purge_cache -a mygreatapp

With a fresh heroku repo,  simply deploy as usual.